# Link an image to a list item in sharepoint2007

Tags: list, 2007, item

good day,
I have a custom list that manages disputes in my company.
What i am trying to do is have a "preset" field that contains a link to an image (or file). This image/file can be clicked and the image would open in a new windows.

The purpose of this is to provide a hierarchy of the company so that people know who to assign the dispute to.

Is this even possible?

Possible Solution: I have tried to do this in a workflow but it only works "AFTER" the item is created, which for me does not serve the purpose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes possible. YOU can have a attach file option in list which show attached items in list. And will show links of files which ha re attached to.

Comment: Thanks, But i want the attachment to be "Preset". Meaning that whenever someone creates a new item, the attachment will automatically be there and there is a visible link to open it. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, exactly I'm trying to say. Attachments links will be there to attached item in newform of list. On the same page, when you attach item a link will added which will be visible.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How to do that though? all i have is a button to attach new files by the person creating a new item. How do i have the system automatically attaach and image or pdf available for a person as soon as they start creating a new item, where they can open and view the attachment?

Comment: Anyone out there aware of how to pre-attach a file to any new list item being created? the same file will be attached to all new list items by the system automatically. Any help would be appreciated !! Thanks

Comment: Anyone? There's got to be a way